# Regex to match file extension in URL

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regular expression [regex101 with test cases](https://regex101.com/r/DI7bZO/1)

```
.{0,}(\.jpg|\.gif).{0,}
```

I'd like to match URLs containing .gif and .jpg extensions at the end of the URL. Unfortunately the domain is named gif.com.

Here are my test cases:

```
1 - http://www.gif.com/test.jpg - should match
2 - http://www.gif.com/test.html - shouldn't match
3 - http://gif.com/test.jpg - should match
4 - http://gif.com/test.html - shouldn't match
```

I'd like to alter the regex to not match in case 2. I've tried some negative lookbehinds for http://www, but I need the regex to match the whole line.

Comment: Use anchors and perhaps make the match a bit more specific `^http://.*\.(?:jpg|gif)$` https://regex101.com/r/u2OHGC/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$` anchor, which means end of string

```
.{0,}(\.jpg|\.gif)$
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/kyLB8d/1)